# Create Default Fields in Inspector with Type input (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can i dynamically create and remove inspector fields by getting, as an input, their type? Is it even possible? The problem i'm trying to solve is: creating a scriptableObject class for every new  child of an abstract class.
For instance, i have a human and, for now, i can only equip him with a sword. When i will finnish with that part of the code i will proceed to make him able to wear armor, but then i have to modify the scriptableObject or prefab of the human to support the new feature. On top of that, what if i don't want for every human to have the ability to wear armor? Prefabs are (i think) one way of solving the problem but it doesn't sit well for me, i want a more data oriented approach.

```cs
foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in customType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
  //do code here to transform fieldInfo into serializedProperty or something else

  EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(/*?*/); //or something else
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(type). You can use methods like EditorGUILayout.IntField() / FloatField() / TextField etc. to generate default fields and ObjectField() for your custom type.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < fieldInfos.Length; i++)
{
    var field = fieldInfos[i];

    _dataStorage[i] = field.FieldType switch
    {
        var type when type == typeof(int) => EditorGUILayout.IntField(label: field.Name, _fieldsInfo[i] is int @int ? @int : 0),
        var type when type == typeof(string) => EditorGUILayout.TextField(label: field.Name, _fieldsInfo[i] is string @str ? @str : ""),
        var type when type == typeof(Color) => EditorGUILayout.ColorField(label: field.Name, _fieldsInfo[i] is Color @clr ? @clr : Color.black),
        var type when type == typeof(float) => EditorGUILayout.FloatField(label: field.Name, _fieldsInfo[i] is float @flt ? @flt : 0f),
        _ => EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(label: field.Name, obj: (UnityEngine.Object)_fieldsInfo[i], field.FieldType, true/*idk for sure*/),
    };
   
}
```

_dataStorage is an object array outside the method that will store you fields data